# Possible to make the child dirty when it changes from the parent?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Lets say I have two classes:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {

    @OneToOne
    private Child child;
}

@Entity
public class Child {

    @OneToOne
    private Parent parent;

    private String name;
}
```

Then I get the the parent class, and via that change the child like so:

```
Parent parent = parentRepo.findOne(id);
parent.getChild().setName("newName");
```

This triggers a Hibernate event (onPostUpdate) for the Child entity, because the name is marked as dirty. This all makes sense.

PostUpdateEvent:

```
@Override
public void onPostUpdate(PostUpdateEvent event) {
    ...
}
```

But is there any way to mark the parent as dirty (because the child was changed), so the Update event gets triggered for the parent?

Comment: If the parent is unchanged, why do you want to update it?

Comment: In this case, i would like to see that the parent is changed. Because the child entity is just an extension of information from the parent.

Comment: I still don't get why you need it but why not manually call onPostUpdate for the parent from the child?

Comment: How wound one manually call the event and populate the PostUpdateEvent object  correct?

Comment: If you have implemented it in your Parent class then call it directly and the parameter could be null I assume since nothing changed. If you don’t want to mess with onPostUpdate then just implement your own method in Parent for this and call it manually

Comment: That is not an option. And is really out-of-scope for this question.